# What is "gauge" size for door hinge knuckles?

Tags: doors, hinges

Anyone know the meaning of "gauge" when talking about the outer diameter of a door hinge's knuckle?

For example, commercial door hinge knuckles often have "gauge" sizes of 0.134 or 0.180.

Doing my own measurements, I'm *guessing* that in this context it means tenth-of-a-meter.  E.g., 0.134 gauge = 13.4 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gauge is a measure of the thickness of the hinge metal.

[image]
 <sub>*source:* [Stanley 5 Knuckle Ball Bearing Hinges](http://www.stanleyhardwarefordoors.com/files/6215/4047/4152/5_Knuckle_BB_Hinges_SAH009_WEB.pdf)</sub>

This would affect the size of the knuckle as it wraps around the hinge pin.

```
size of knuckle = (hinge gauge x 2) + hinge pin diameter (+ a bit to allow for clearance)
```

Heavy weight gauges increase available bearing surface area. It will also determine the depth of the cut-out recess(es) in the door/door frame necessary for a flush installation.

The gauge also determines the type of 'hinge tweaker' tool you need.

[image]
    <sub>Hinge Tweaker Heavy Weight Size for .180 Gauge Hinges</sub>

You need a more robust tool with a wider 'mouth' to 'tweak' .180 Gauge Hinges than .123 Gauge Hinges